# Rotate object parallell to line

Tags: vector, inkscape, transform, rotate

Suppose I have an object *A* containing a line segment *l*. Now I have another line segment *q* in my drawing. How can I rotate the whole object *A* such that the line segment *l* becomes parallell to *q*?

I've done this manually by now, but it takes time and doesn't get exact.

**PS:** It's OK for me that the object *A* gets translated; *A* does not need to be at the same place after rotation.

---

Original:

[image: original]

Result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Node snapping will help. Enable the following from the node snapping toolbar:

1. *Enable snapping* <kbd>%</kbd>, the first button in the toolbar.
2. *Snap nodes, paths and handles* (important!)
3. *Snap to paths*
4. *Snap cusp nodes*
5. *Snap smooth nodes*
6. *Snap other points...*
7. *Snap an item's rotation center* (important!)

Some of the above snapping options may be unneeded, and depend on your path.

Now, select path *A* twice so you can see the rotation handles and the rotation center.

Drag the rotation center to one of the endpoints of line segment *I*; snapping should get you exactly there.

Now, drag the whole path so that the rotation center snaps to line segment *q*.

Now you can rotate path *A* so that the other endpoint of line segment *I* snaps to line segment *q*.

If *q* is too short compared to *I*, you can duplicate *q* and transform it into a guide (<kbd>shifg-G</kbd>). Now you can drag this guide and keep the angle. Snap to the guide rather than *q* (after enabling *snap to guides*).

Comment: Thank you - snapping was the kind of solution I was looking for! And transform into a guide was a thing I didn't know existed, but had been missing :)